# How to disable click outside of react native modal area to close modal ? Close pop up when click on CLOSE button only in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-modal

When I clicked outside the modal, the pop-up was closing. Is there any way, when I click on the close button, only that should close the popup.
Instead of closing when someone clicks outside. It should close on the close button only.

<TouchableWithoutFeedback  onPress={() => { setVisible(false); }}>

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<TouchableWithoutFeedback
onPress={() => { setVisible(false); }>

When we keep setVisible (false) and click outside the pop-up, it will close it. To make a pop-up close on the CLOSE button, you have to make it like:

<TouchableWithoutFeedback
onPress={() => { **setVisible(true)**; }>

**Explanation**

This is basically using a TouchableOpacity in the whole screen to get when the user clicks to close the modal. The TouchableWithoutFeedback is to avoid the TouchableOpacity to work inside of the Modal.